# Set style to innerHTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a Skate Dice program and have run into a wall. I want my JavaScript to get an element and then style the innerHTML.

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>GameSpace</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
 <body>
<input id="roll" type="button" value="Roll" onclick="show1()"/>
<img id="img1" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/X/w/P/Y/q/H/dice-1-md.png"/>

<img id="img2" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/X/V/S/C/I/x/dice-2-md.png"/>

<img id="img3" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/n/O/d/R/Y/c/dice-3-md.png"/>

<img id="img4" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/D/j/Z/R/5/P/dice-4-md.png"/>
<div id="popup"><p id="intext"> The dice have rolled! </p></div>
<script>
function reload()
{
window.location.reload(),
setTimeout(10000);
}

var rolldie1 = Math.random(), answer1; 

if (rolldie1 <= 0.16)
  {
    answer1 = "Ollie";
  } else if (rolldie1 <= 0.32)
    {
      answer1 ="Nollie";
    }
 else if (rolldie1 <= 0.48)
    {
      answer1 ="Fakie";
    }
 else if (rolldie1 <= 0.64)
    {
      answer1 ="Nose";
    }
 else if (rolldie1 <= 0.32)
    {
      answer1 ="Tail";
    }
 else if (rolldie1 <= 0.99)
    {
      answer1 ="Premo";
    }
function show1()
{
  var elem = document.getElementById("popup");
    elem.style.display = "block";

    document.getElementById("popup").innerHTML = document.getElementById("intext");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want document.getElementById to get the popup and the innerHTML is text, but it is far too small, so i want it to get a paragraph element for the innerHTML.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: You already have the popup element, are you saying that you want the style of the text in the popup to be larger?

Comment: Yes, the text inside the popup needs to be bigger

Comment: Use a CSS class to define what the text should look like, then apply that class name to the element at the appropriate time.

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks, why was i down voted? I did my research and i'm not good with javascript.

Comment: I suppose you were downvoted because you got ahead of yourself and asked a question which really doesn't make any sense. elem.innerHTML is just a text string, not a DOM element. You can't style a text string. It's just characters. So it's a confusing question. (I didn't downvote it, I'm just speculating)

Comment: Ok well, i got it now anyway, if you want the code for it just ask